# Could someone help me understand why this MySQL update code isn't working php 5

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

Here is the code. It seems to be having an issue in PHP 5. It works well in PHP 4.4.9.

```
if($_REQUEST['action']== "Update"){ 

    $curDate = date("Y-m-d");
    $image =$_FILES['vImage']["name"];
    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['vImage']['tmp_name'];


$sql="UPDATE businessad 
        SET iBUserID= '$_REQUEST[iBUserID]', 
            iCategoryID= '$_REQUEST[iBCategoryID]', 
            vAdTitle= '$_REQUEST[vAdTitle]', 
            tAdText= '$_REQUEST[tAdText]',
            vAdImage= '$vAdImage', 
            vAdURL= '$_REQUEST[vAdURL]', 
            dStartDate= '$_REQUEST[dStartDate]',
            dEndDate= '$_REQUEST[dEndDate]', 
            vAddress1= '$_REQUEST[vAddress1]', 
            vAddress2= '$_REQUEST[vAddress2]',
            vCity= '$_REQUEST[vCity]',
            vState= '$_REQUEST[vState]', 
            vZipCode= '$_REQUEST[vZipCode]', 
            vPhone= '$_REQUEST[vPhone]', 
            vEmail= '$_REQUEST[vEmail]', 
            eStatus='$_REQUEST[eStatus]' 

        WHERE iBusAdID='".$_REQUEST['iBusAdID']."'";

$db_sql=$obj->sql_query($sql);

if($db_sql)
{   
    $msg=MSG_UPDATE;
    header("Location:businessadview.php?var_msg=$msg");
    exit;
}
else
{
    $msg=MSG_UPDATE_ERROR;
    header("Location:businessadview.php?var_msg=$msg");
    exit;
```

That code doesn't update to the MySQL table, and I'm not sure why.

What precedes the above code is a form that looks like this

```
<form name="frmadd" method="post" action="businessadadd_a.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="<?=$action;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="iBusAdID" value=<?=$iBusAdID;?>>
```

I check my server error logs and found out this. It mentions some errors in the globals.php, which is a part of the include call up. I'll include the include code too.

Here is the include code

```
<?php

@session_start();

@ob_start();

include_once("./lib/db_config.php");

include_once("./lib/myclass.php");

include_once("./lib/globals.php");

    if(!isset($obj)){

    $obj = new myclass($SERVER,$DBASE,$USERNAME,$PASSWORD);

     }

include_once("./lib/generalsettings.php");

include_once("./function/general.php");

include_once("./lib/messages.php");

getGeneralVar();

?>
```

Here is the globals.php code that the server error logs have an issue with

```
  <?php

     $glob=array("SERVER");

if(isset($GPC_vars))
{ foreach($GPC_vars as $var)
   { foreach(array("GET","POST","COOKIE") as $avar)
       if(isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_".$avar."_VARS"][$var]))
         { $$var=$GLOBALS["HTTP_".$avar."_VARS"][$var];
         }
   }               
}
else
{ $glob=array_merge(array("GET","POST","COOKIE"),$glob);
}

foreach($glob as $avar)
{ $arr=$GLOBALS["HTTP_".$avar."_VARS"];
  foreach($arr as $var => $res)
       $$var=$res;
}

foreach ($HTTP_POST_FILES as $name => $value) {
    $$name = $value["tmp_name"];
    foreach($value as $k=>$v) {
        $varname_ = $name."_".$k;
        $$varname_ = $v;
    }
}
reset($HTTP_POST_FILES);
?>
```

Here is what the error logs say

[Mon Mar 14 13:08:55 2011] [error] [client -] File does not exist: /public_html/favicon.ico

[Mon Mar 14 13:08:54 2011] [error] [client -] PHP Warning:  reset() [function.reset]: Passed variable is not an array or object in /public_html/lib/globals.php on line 30, referer: xxx.com/admin/businessadadd.php?iBusAdID=4&action=Update

[Mon Mar 14 13:08:54 2011] [error] [client -] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in .../public_html/lib/globals.php on line 23, referer: xxx.com/admin/businessadadd.php?iBusAdID=4&action=Update

[Mon Mar 14 13:08:54 2011] [error] [client -] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in .../public_html/lib/globals.php on line 19, referer: xxx.com/admin/businessadadd.php?iBusAdID=4&action=Update

[Mon Mar 14 13:08:54 2011] [error] [client -] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in .../public_html/lib/globals.php on line 19, referer: xxx.com/admin/businessadadd.php?iBusAdID=4&action=Update

[Mon Mar 14 13:08:54 2011] [error] [client -] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in .../public_html/lib/globals.php on line 19, referer: xxx.com/admin/businessadadd.php?iBusAdID=4&action=Update

[Mon Mar 14 13:08:54 2011] [error] [client -] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in .../public_html/lib/globals.php on line 19, referer: xxx.com/admin/businessadadd.php?iBusAdID=4&action=Update

Comment: Did you call mysql_query on the sql? Did you call mysql_connect?

Comment: PHP 5 changed the order in which GET/POST/etc variables are written into the REQUEST super-global.  Are there duplicate variables in the query string and form submission?  Also, I would put ALL of those variable substitutions outside of the string (like the last one iBusAdID is) and obviously would make sure that data was validated/sanitized.

Comment: There are a lot of unknowns here.  Have you checked that the db has a table called businessad?  How are you connecting to the database?  Is there a connection to the database?  Are all the fields you have listed in the database?  If any of the fields are not exactly how you have it in the database then that could cause issues too...

Comment: the database does have that table. There is a connection to the database in a include file. All the fields are listed are in the database. That's why it troubles me that it wasn't updating. I'm trying the "array_map snippet" suggested below.

Comment: @Big Freeze: Can you just put this line: echo $sql; right after above line in your code and tell us what does it show in browser? php might be writing actual error to a error log file (defined in your php.ini) and that's why your screen goes blank.

Comment: @anubhava, I checked my server logs, and I seem to have the issue with the globals.php file. I have posted the code up there. I think the issue is with looping through the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try to use the concatenation you are doing at the end within the query.  It might be look at the `$_REQUEST['SOMETHING']` as a string.

```
$sql = "UPDATE businessad 
           SET iBUserID = '".$_REQUEST['iBUserID']."',
               iCategoryID = '".$_REQUEST['iBCategoryID']."',    
               vAdTitle = '".$_REQUEST['vAdTitle']."', 
               tAdText = '".$_REQUEST['tAdText']."',
               vAdImage = '$vAdImage', 
               vAdURL = '".$_REQUEST['vAdURL']."', 
               dStartDate = '".$_REQUEST['dStartDate']."',
               dEndDate = '".$_REQUEST['dEndDate']."', 
               vAddress1 = '".$_REQUEST['vAddress1']."', 
               vAddress2 = '".$_REQUEST['vAddress2']."',
               vCity = '".$_REQUEST['vCity']."',
               vState = '".$_REQUEST['vState']."', 
               vZipCode = '".$_REQUEST['vZipCode']."', 
               vPhone = '".$_REQUEST['vPhone']."', 
               vEmail= '".$_REQUEST['vEmail']."', 
               eStatus = '".$_REQUEST['eStatus']."'    
         WHERE iBusAdID = '".$_REQUEST['iBusAdID']."'";
```

Answer (score 2):

Because it's just a string. Do you execute the query? If so, what does mysql_error tell you?

And please, pretty please, Google for SQL injection. This code is very vulnerable.

Comment: I'll try the echo right now to see if it says any error. Right now, it doesn't say anything. The page just goes blank, and nothing gets updated to the sql table.  I have it normally output a message that says "update completed".  I'm also pretty new to programming, so I have to put SQL injection worries on my list of things to cover for security. Thanks.

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi. How is it not? mysql_error might very well return useful information about this query or any other statement. There's a lot that can go wrong in the migration from PHP 4 to 5 and a best quess should be to check if the query is valid (how is the data posted, is it exactly the same and handled the same too) and if the mysql functions work correctly. It may not be a complete answer which is near impossible due to the lack of information, but it's a serious attempt to point OP in the right direction.

Comment: Well it seems like you haven't fully digested my answer. But where I did at least try to be constructive you just started downvoting because of the first few words. I'm sorry I cost you points...

Answer (score 2):

The reason its failing is explained by your statement:

> and I'm not sure why

1) you've cited a fragment of the code used to generate the query - but we need to see the query which gets sent to the database **and** the structure of the table

2) we also need to see the error message that is returned after the query fails.

3) since you are using $_REQUEST, we also need to see your variables_order setting for both PHP installations to determine how $_REQUEST is populated

I expect once you find the answers to these the solution will be obvious. But it's also worth noting that splicing user supplied data into an SQL query is a very bad idea - you're wide open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question to show the condition that sends the info to the sql table. I'm also showing what the error logs says, and the affected code from the error logs. The variables_order for the php 4.4.9 server says 0, whilst that for the php 5.2.14 says EGPCS

Comment: Here is the table structure -  iBusAdID, iBUserID, iCategoryID, vAdTitle, tAdText, vAdImage, vAdURL, dStartDate, dEndDate, eStatus,  vAddress1, vAddress2, vEmail, vCity, vState, vPhone, vZipCode

Answer (score 0):

When you say your code works in PHP4 but stops working in PHP5, then it's easy to assume this is due to lack of **magic_quotes**. This feature has been disabled in the default configurations of PHP5. And your SQL query now became invalid due to lack of escaping.

At the start of your script (but after the mysql_connect) add following:

```
$_REQUEST = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $_REQUEST);
```

It's workaround-ish, but at least safe if it is **always** executed right after the database connection. Do the same for $_GET and $_POST if you must. (The correct approach would be to migrate to PDO and parameterized SQL, or at least apply the mysql_real_escape_string function **wherever** you concatenate SQL queries.)

Comment: I don't have the mysql_connect code preceding that line of code, because I have an include file that is automatically loaded on every page with the connect parameters.

Comment: Add the array_map snippet after the mysql_connect. If it's in a separate connect file, then do it there.